# Simplify the oracle query without UNION syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I already post the same with mistake. So asking the same question with correction. Is it possible to avoid UNION in this query? Can anyone help on this query? Thanks in advance

```
SELECT A.M_TITLE, 
       A.M_NUMBER, 
       B.M_NAME, 
       B.M_DESCRIPTION, 
       A.FORM_TYPE, 
       B.SUBMISSION_DATE, 
       B.CREATON_DATE, 
       A.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORM_ID,
       B.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORMDATA_ID, 
       ''            AS ATTACHMENTS 
FROM M_FORM A, 
     M_FORMDATA B 
WHERE A.M_NUMBER = B.M_NUMBER 
AND ANY B.ATTACHMENTS IN 
    (SELECT ATTACHMENTS FROM M_FORMDATA C WHERE B.M_NUMBER = C.M_NUMBER) 
AND ACTION_ID = 'XXXX' 
AND SUBMISSION_DATE >= DATE('XXXX') 
AND SUBMISSION_DATE <= DATE('XXXX') 

UNION 

SELECT A.M_TITLE, 
       A.M_NUMBER, 
       B.M_NAME, 
       B.M_DESCRIPTION, 
       A.FORM_TYPE, 
       B.SUBMISSION_DATE, 
       B.CREATION_DATE, 
       A.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORM_ID,
       B.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORMDATA_ID, 
       'null'        AS ATTACHMENTS 
 FROM M_FORM A, 
      M_FORMDATA 
 WHERE A.M_NUMBER = B.M_NUMBER 
 AND NOT ANY B.ATTACHMENTS IN 
      (SELECT ATTACHMENTS FROM M_FORMDATA C WHERE B.M_NUMBER = C.M_NUMBER) 
 AND ACTION_ID= 'XXXX' 
 AND SUBMISSION_DATE >= DATE('XXXX') 
 AND SUBMISSION_DATE <= DATE('XXXX')
```

Comment: What is wrong using `UNION` ?

Comment: CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END

Comment: Simplification is for performance. Can we write this query without UNION?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the query correctly, the only difference is in how `ATTACHMENTS` is defined.  You can make that conditional:

```
SELECT A.M_TITLE, 
       A.M_NUMBER, 
       B.M_NAME, 
       B.M_DESCRIPTION, 
       A.FORM_TYPE, 
       B.SUBMISSION_DATE, 
       B.CREATON_DATE, 
       A.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORM_ID,
       B.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORMDATA_ID, 
       (case when B.ATTACHMENTS IN (SELECT ATTACHMENTS FROM M_FORMDATA C WHERE B.M_NUMBER = C.M_NUMBER) 
             then ''
        end) AS ATTACHMENTS 
FROM M_FORM A join
     M_FORMDATA B 
     on A.M_NUMBER = B.M_NUMBER 
WHERE ACTION_ID = 'XXXX' AND
      SUBMISSION_DATE >= DATE('XXXX') AND SUBMISSION_DATE <= DATE('XXXX') ;
```

I also changed the `join` syntax to use explicit joins (with the `on` clause).

Comment: A Parser Error (syntax error) has occurred in the vicinity of: (case when"

Comment: @user1636102 . . . Something like that often happens when there is a missing comma on the preceding line.  If you put your table definitions on SQL Fiddle, I can look at it there.